# Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a word generating tool that takes the supplied words and adds various manglings to it.

Now I am achieving what I am trying to do but my method seems very long winded. Is there a better way to do this?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

words = raw_input("Enter Word!: ")


def add_numbers(wordlist):
    parts = wordlist.split()
    numbers_list = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

    try:
        value1 = parts[0]
        value2 = parts[1]
        value3 = parts[2]
        value4 = parts[3]
        value5 = parts[4]
    except IndexError:
        bads = 'null'

    try: value1
    except NameError: value1 = None
    try: value2
    except NameError: value2 = None
    try: value3
    except NameError: value3 = None
    try: value4
    except NameError: value4 = None
    try: value5
    except NameError: value5 = None

    if value1 is None:
        pass
    else:
        first_list = []
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6])+str(numbers_list[7]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6])+str(numbers_list[7])+str(numbers_list[8]))
        first_list.append(value1+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6])+str(numbers_list[7])+str(numbers_list[8])+str(numbers_list[9]))
        print first_list

    if value2 is None:
        pass
    else:
        second_list = []
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6])+str(numbers_list[7]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6])+str(numbers_list[7])+str(numbers_list[8]))
        second_list.append(value2+str(numbers_list[0])+str(numbers_list[1])+str(numbers_list[2])+str(numbers_list[3])+str(numbers_list[4])+str(numbers_list[5])+str(numbers_list[6])+str(numbers_list[7])+str(numbers_list[8])+str(numbers_list[9]))
        print second_list
```

Comment: This is something indeed

Comment: lol yes, can see why I think there must be a better way :)

Comment: I have made a slight improvement

Comment: That's not an improvement, it's a change; passing a list to `str` is not the same as concatenating the individual elements made into strings. `str(1) + str(2) == '12'`, while `str([1,2]) == '[1, 2]'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this?

```
worldlist = "test hello world"
parts = worldlist.split()
values = list(range(1,11))
mangled = []
for part in parts:
    l = []
    val = ''
    for x in values:
        val += str(x)
        l.append(part + val)
    mangled.append(l)

for l in mangled:
    print(l)
```

results:

```
['test0', 'test01', 'test012', 'test0123', 'test01234', 'test012345', 'test0123456', 'test01234567', 'test012345678', 'test0123456789', 'test012345678910']
['hello0', 'hello01', 'hello012', 'hello0123', 'hello01234', 'hello012345', 'hello0123456', 'hello01234567', 'hello012345678', 'hello0123456789', 'hello012345678910']
['world0', 'world01', 'world012', 'world0123', 'world01234', 'world012345', 'world0123456', 'world01234567', 'world012345678', 'world0123456789', 'world012345678910']
```

Comment: Glad to help. I remember being a python noob :)

If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a slight amendment to get rid of the 0 as I dont need it 'values[:] = (value for value in values if value != 0)'

Comment: I'll make an edit to include that in a way that in my opinion is _cleaner_.

Look at my call to range

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the top:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

words = raw_input("Enter Word!: ")

def add_numbers(wordlist):
    parts = wordlist.split()
    numbers_list = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
```

Here, you can add the various defaults to the end of `parts`, so they get used if you "run out" of `parts` prematurely. I'm ignoring `bads`, since you never seem to use it.

```
    value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 = (parts + [None]*5)[:5]
```

There's almost never any reason to use `pass` with a conditional statement. Here, you can simply invert the test and ignore the `else`.

```
    if value1 is not None:
```

You make repeated use of the same subexpressions, so save the results so that you don't need to do the same thing over and over again. Essentially, you just want to accumulate a value while iterating over `numbers_list`

```
        first_list = []
        str_value = str(value1)
        for num_value in numbers_list:
            str_value += num_value
            first_list.append(str_value)

        print first_list
```

And do likewise for `value2` et al.

```
    if value2 is not None:

        second_list = []
        str_value = str(value1)
        for num_value in numbers_list:
            str_value += num_value
            second_list.append(str_value)

        print second_list
```

You probably want to use a list of values, rather than 5 separate `value1`, `value2`, etc variables, but I leave that as an exercise to make that replacement.

Comment: You'll need a catchall in the tuple-expansion: `value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 , *rest = parts + [None]*5` otherwise python will complain about too many arguments to unpack.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to add the slice to the end: `(parts + [None]*5)[:5]`. That catchall syntax doesn't work prior to Python 3, though.

Comment: Thanks, much more elegant already lol, however ideally the raw_input should take as many words as the user supplies with a space inbetween. eg word1 word2 word3 etc. Is there a way to maybe auto generate the variable name if a 5th or 6th word is available?

Comment: Like I said, you really want to use a single list rather than a set of similarly named variables. That actually simplifies things greatly, since you no longer have to worry about whether `value283` is `None` or not. You simply use `values[i]` for some value of `i` less than `len(values)`.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly have hard time understanding what you *really* wanted to achieve but here is more compact code that produces identical result:

```
def add_numbers(wordlist):
    parts = wordlist.split()

    for x in xrange(0, 2):
        if len(parts) < x+1:
            pass
        else:
            s = parts[x]
            some_list = [s]
            for i in xrange(1, 11):
                s += str(i)
                some_list.append(s)
            print some_list


add_numbers('Carl stole corals from Clara')
```